# Working process of converting python programs to executables in windows using pyinstaller

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, software-design

I wanted to convert one of my python projects into executables or some application for windows such that they will operate without going into python interface and running it from there. A quick search revealed the existence of pyinstaller and I used it. When I read it's working at its official site the following statement was there: "The PyInstaller bootloader is a binary executable program for the active platform (Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, etc.). When the user launches your program, it is the bootloader that runs. The bootloader creates a temporary Python environment such that the Python interpreter will find all imported modules and libraries in the myscript folder."

Now what I want to know is if the resulting .exe file is used on some other system is it necessary to install pyinstaller so that bootloader can be activated? Also is it necessary to have all the required python modules and libraries so that bootloader can create a temporary environment? Can we make changes to the given interface? And what other ways are there to change .py files to .exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyinstaller will compile the Python file and all necessary libraries/modules into the exe file. You can then run it on another computer without the need to install any other programms.

*When the user launches your program, it is the bootloader that runs. The bootloader creates a temporary Python environment such that the Python interpreter will find all imported modules and libraries in the myscript folder.*
What this means is that when you run the executable, a command style window will start, in which the python code will run. This window will also show all error messages, print statements, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also asked about how to change the interface of exe file if we are using pyinstaller and other ways to convert it into exe file. Can you also answer that?

Comment: What do you mean by "changing the interface of the exe file"? You can choose to suppress the command style window when you create the exe file with Pyinstaller (it's one of the options). See [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#options) for all the options. An alternative to Pyinstaller is py2exe, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: What I mean is how to make it more interactive like adding a menu or changing background colour etc.?

Comment: Please create separate question about re-styling of Pyinstaller UI (if it does not exist already).

Comment: Pyinstaller itself will only make your python code stand-alone executable. To make it more interactive, different color, etc., you will have to change your Python script itself. For example Tkinter is a flexible module to create a GUI around your script.